# what is the right way to get question on top of list again

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, rules

this might sound against the policy of SO, but I am looking for an acceptable way by which if a question has gone down the list without any answers, how can we pull that back up ?

There are times when you post a question and not the right members are online, but a day later the question is piled under loads of new questions and hence it gets difficult to get a response.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: If you edit the question it will appear in the top of the "Active" list of the related tags. Try not to do lots of minor edits though, because the people that follow the tags may be irritated by the unnecessary activity.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions

Comment: I usually look for newest questions rather than active ones, are most people looking at active list ?

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39939/248731

Answer (score 8):

You can set a [bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) to get more exposure.